# Deploying an Apache Airflow with Dokku (based on heroku)

Tags: docker, airflow, dokku

I have a cloud machine with Dokku (Docker powered mini-Heroku) installed and many apps.

Actually, i need to deploy an Apache Airflow app on my infrastructure.

The image of Apache Airflow :
https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow

Anyone has already deploy it with dokku ?

I tried to push the Dockerfile to my app but the deployment failed.

Comment: Can you share some details about the failure you observed? Also what do you mean by "you tried to push the Dockerfile"?

Comment: There are no details of the failure observed... I mean i tried the Dockerfile Deployment from Dokku (commit a valid Dockerfile to the root of the repository and push the repository to the Dokku installation). I think the problem is about the configuration of the database of airflow (Airflow need a db to store metadata), not sure.. but i will try something.